# How to get the relative path in spring controller to get resources

Tags: spring-mvc

in my project my file dir is like this  -->projectname  ->src  ->WebContent  ->images  ->WEB-INF      I am using above file path. but I am getting error "The system cannot find the path specified". I want to get the image from the "images" folder. please help me to get the relative path of images folder in Controller. I am using the code `File newFile = new File("/./images/userimages/"+fileName);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the resource loader from Spring.

```
public class YourClass implements ResourceLoaderAware {
  private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

  resourceLoader.getResource("./images/userimages/" + file);

   @Override
   public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
      this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
   }

}
```

Comment: Is that property magically set or does one need to annotate it with @Autowired or mark it's class with the `ResourceLoaderAware` interface?

Comment: Sorry but you forgot to implement the interface.